# Delaying Query ulSlide plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

So I am using the fantastic **jQuery ulSlide plugin**.
However I would like to have a delay on the animation.
The `.delay()` function doesn't seem to work when calling the plug-in.
Any suggestions?

Site: http://www.carlpapworth.com/friday-quiz/#

Html:

```
<ul id="qBox">
<!--Q1-->           <li class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion">Question I                       </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer a</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer b</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer c</h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
<!--Q2-->           <li class="qContainer">
                        <div class="qQuestion">Question II                      </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer 1</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer 2</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer 3</h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
<!--Q3-->           <li class="qContainer">
                        <div  class="qQuestion">Question III                        </div>
                        <ul class="qAnswers">
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer 1</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer 2</h3></a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class=""><h3>Answer 3</h3></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
</ul>
```

Custom-JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
                    $('#qBox').ulslide({
                            effect: {
                                type: 'slide', // slide or fade
                                axis: 'x',     // x, y
                                distance: 0   // Distance between frames
                            },
                            duration: 2000,
                            autoslide: 0,
                            width: 500,
                            height: 300,
                            mousewheel: false,
                            nextButton: '.qAnswers a',
                            prevButton: '#e1_prev'
                    }); 
});
```

Comment: Are you saying you want to wait 200 ms for the animation to start? Anyways, you'll probably need to use setTimeout in some form or another.

Comment: Yes exactly. Where do I implement it? In the plug-in-code?